# Using two separate mutexes for the Exclusive Queue Problem (Little Book of Semaphores)

Tags: concurrency, synchronization

I recently read the exclusive queue (exclusive ballroom dancers) problem on the "Little Book of Semaphores" by Allen Downey.

His solution included a single mutex for both the leaders and the followers. Could there be anything wrong with using two separate mutexes for leaders and followers? After all, a check is done at the end of the dance part. Below is my solution.

Initialization:

```
semaphore leaderMutex = 1;
semaphore followerMutex = 1;
semaphore leaderHasFinished=0;
semaphore followerHasFinished=0;
int numLeaders=0;
int numFollowers=0;
```

Leader:

```
leaderMutex.wait();
numLeaders++;
while(numFollowers<=0);
dance();
numLeaders--;
leaderHasFinished.signal();
followerHasFinished.wait();
leaderMutex.signal();
```

Follower:

```
followerMutex.wait();
numFollowers++;
while(numLeaders<=0);
dance();
numFollowers--;
followerHasFinished.signal();
leaderHasFinished.wait();
followerMutex.signal();
```

Comment: Please describe/define the *exclusive queue/ballroom dancers* problem. I don't know it, and don't have the book.

Comment: Also, way too much code (with mysterious semantics).  My eyes glazed over and I can't figure out why your solution has 4 semaphores when you are looking for a solution with just 2 mutexes.

Comment: @WanderingLogic The problem is described as follows: Imagine that threads represent ballroom dancers and that two kinds of dancers, leaders and followers, wait in two queues before entering the dance floor. When a leader arrives, it checks to see if there is a follower waiting. If so, they can both proceed. Otherwise it waits. Similarly, when a follower arrives, it checks for a leader and either proceeds or waits, accordingly. Also, there is a constraint that each leader can invoke dance concurrently with only one follower, and vice versa.

Comment: @WanderingLogic Oops, with mutexes I meant a semaphore that can only accept 1 process accessing a shared resource. Downey used 1 mutex in his book while I used 2, and I'm wondering if there's an effect to not using just 1.